# Replace a whole line in a INI-file using Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

i have a problem with replacing a whole line in a ini-file, it just seems to add my result to thesame line.

Here is the ini-file:

```
    [environment]
APP_USER=Domain\User1
```

I just wish to replace the APP_USER=Domain\User1 with for example APP_USER=Domain\User2.

Here is my code:

```
$USER = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name          
(Get-Content D:\Test\test.ini) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "APP_USER=" , "APP_USER=$user" } | Set-Content D:\Test\test.ini
```

I get this result when i use the above code:

```
    [environment]
APP_USER=Domain\User2Domain\User1
```

Help would be much appreciated.

//Regard PMS

Answer (score 21):

To match the whole line:

```
-replace "APP_USER=.+","APP_USER=$user"
```

The `.+` will match the rest of the line.

Comment: @user2400659, good to hear, don't forget to mark the correct as appropriate.

Comment: .+ was what I needed.  Spent some time looking for this one.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2400659, (or anyone) what if you want to remove the matched line, including the \n newline?  This solution helped me blank out lines I want removed, based on whether they contain a string.  But then I end up with hundreds of empty newlines in the file, scattered everywhere.  :-(